I made two plots using par(), but it doesn't save
I made a function where I read a .csv file, process the data into the dataframe, make a boxplot and barplot in a (2, 1) layout, and save in png file. If I run a function, it does show the correct dataframe, but the plots are not saved. If I run the plot code independently, Rstudio shows the plots correctly though.
data <- read.csv("file name here", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

F4 <- function(data) {
  data <- data[, !colnames(data) %in% "blank"]
  names(data) <- c("district", "confirmed", "deceased", "recovered")
  data[,"active"] <- data$confirmed - data$recovered - data$deceased
  data <- data[, c("district", "active", "confirmed", "recovered", "deceased")]
  data <- data[1:30, ]
  return(data)
  
  png("png file name here", width=100, height=500)
  
  par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar = c(4, 4, 4, 4), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  boxplot(data$active, data$confirmed, data$recovered, data$deceased, col = "skyblue", ylab = "No. of Cases",
          main = "Boxplot of COVID-19 status")
  axis(1, at = 1, labels = "Active")
  axis(1, at = 2, labels = "Confirmed")
  axis(1, at = 3, labels = "Recovered")
  axis(1, at = 4, labels = "Deceased")
  barplot(data$confirmed, col = "skyblue", ylim = c(0, 200), names.arg = 1:30,
          xlab = "District", ylab = "No. of Cases", main = "COVID-19 status by region")
  barplot(data$recovered, col = "yellowgreen", add = TRUE)
  barplot(data$deceased, col = "tomato", add = TRUE)
  legend("topright", legend = c("Confirmed", "Recovered", "Deceased"), fill=c("skyblue", "yellowgreen", "tomato"), horiz=TRUE, cex = 0.9)
  
  dev.off()
}



Use the return after plotting. Also ensure that width= and height= are large enough. To avoid legend overlap, make a dynamic ylim=(0, max(data$confirmed)*1.1).
F4 <- function(data) {
  data <- data[, !colnames(data) %in% "blank"]
  names(data) <- c("district", "confirmed", "deceased", "recovered")
  data[, "active"] <- data$confirmed - data$recovered - data$deceased
  data <- data[, c("district", "active", "confirmed", "recovered", "deceased")]
  data <- data[1:30, ]
  png("foo.png", width=800, height=1000)
  par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  boxplot(data$active, data$confirmed, data$recovered, data$deceased,
          col="skyblue", ylab="No. of Cases", 
          main="Boxplot of COVID-19 status")
  axis(1, at=1, labels="Active")
  axis(1, at=2, labels="Confirmed")
  axis(1, at=3, labels="Recovered")
  axis(1, at=4, labels="Deceased")
  barplot(data$confirmed, col="skyblue", ylim=c(0, max(data$confirmed)*1.1), 
          names.arg=1:30, xlab="District", ylab="No. of Cases",
          main="COVID-19 status by region")
  barplot(data$recovered, col="yellowgreen", add=TRUE)
  barplot(data$deceased, col="tomato", add=TRUE)
  legend("topright", legend=c("Confirmed", "Recovered", "Deceased"), 
         fill=c("skyblue", "yellowgreen", "tomato"), horiz=TRUE, cex=0.9)
  dev.off()
  return(data)
}


> F4(data)
      district active confirmed recovered deceased
1   District 1     -2        98        91        9
2   District 2     27       114        48       39
3   District 3     99       123        20        4
4   District 4     89       195        74       32
5   District 5     61       171        62       48
6   District 6     -1        98        61       38
7   District 7     81       177        61       35
8   District 8    -64        96       116       44
9   District 9    -12        73        44       41
10 District 10    -22       120       134        8
11 District 11     70       149        51       28
12 District 12     27       138       100       11
13 District 13    107       159        33       19
14 District 14    -69        69       130        8
15 District 15     96       163        25       42
16 District 16     64       160        62       34
17 District 17     20       180       132       28
18 District 18    -57        90       132       15
19 District 19     52       138        50       36
20 District 20    -64        76       113       27
21 District 21     88       158        25       45
22 District 22     -7        54        57        4
23 District 23      0       141       114       27
24 District 24    127       153        25        1
25 District 25    -68        52       103       17
26 District 26     50       107        34       23
27 District 27    -10        91        53       48
28 District 28     25        73        31       17
29 District 29    -59        92       147        4
30 District 30     87       192        60       45



Data:
> dput(data)
structure(list(district = c("District 1", "District 2", "District 3", 
"District 4", "District 5", "District 6", "District 7", "District 8", 
"District 9", "District 10", "District 11", "District 12", "District 13", 
"District 14", "District 15", "District 16", "District 17", "District 18", 
"District 19", "District 20", "District 21", "District 22", "District 23", 
"District 24", "District 25", "District 26", "District 27", "District 28", 
"District 29", "District 30", "District 31", "District 32", "District 33", 
"District 34", "District 35", "District 36", "District 37", "District 38", 
"District 39", "District 40", "District 41", "District 42", "District 43", 
"District 44", "District 45", "District 46", "District 47", "District 48", 
"District 49", "District 50"), confirmed = c(98L, 114L, 123L, 
195L, 171L, 98L, 177L, 96L, 73L, 120L, 149L, 138L, 159L, 69L, 
163L, 160L, 180L, 90L, 138L, 76L, 158L, 54L, 141L, 153L, 52L, 
107L, 91L, 73L, 92L, 192L, 199L, 107L, 185L, 85L, 117L, 195L, 
158L, 141L, 53L, 148L, 163L, 55L, 183L, 179L, 165L, 52L, 167L, 
198L, 51L, 151L), deceased = c(9L, 39L, 4L, 32L, 48L, 38L, 35L, 
44L, 41L, 8L, 28L, 11L, 19L, 8L, 42L, 34L, 28L, 15L, 36L, 27L, 
45L, 4L, 27L, 1L, 17L, 23L, 48L, 17L, 4L, 45L, 39L, 39L, 20L, 
35L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 17L, 26L, 12L, 18L, 31L, 15L, 28L, 16L, 43L, 
8L, 20L, 42L, 47L), recovered = c(91L, 48L, 20L, 74L, 62L, 61L, 
61L, 116L, 44L, 134L, 51L, 100L, 33L, 130L, 25L, 62L, 132L, 132L, 
50L, 113L, 25L, 57L, 114L, 25L, 103L, 34L, 53L, 31L, 147L, 60L, 
85L, 75L, 117L, 44L, 111L, 126L, 80L, 33L, 143L, 114L, 51L, 47L, 
137L, 56L, 132L, 24L, 54L, 97L, 33L, 141L), blank = c(-1.66109907991481, 
-0.382333726873818, -0.5126502578778, 2.7018910003448, -1.36211623118972, 
0.137256218558607, -1.49362506731629, -1.4704357414368, 0.124702386197007, 
-0.996639134884037, -0.0018226143047082, -0.428258881425815, 
-0.613671606449495, -2.02467784541911, -1.22474795035999, 0.179516441117938, 
0.567620594423535, -0.492877353553475, 6.28840653511241e-05, 
1.12288964337997, 1.43985574297619, -1.09711376840582, -0.117319560250177, 
1.2014984009197, -0.469729580566301, -0.0524694849389963, -0.0861072982370896, 
-0.887679017906432, -0.444684004884738, -0.0294448790882381, 
-0.413868849057924, 1.1133860233682, -0.480992841653982, -0.433169032600729, 
0.696862576552103, -1.05636841317091, -0.0406984751512149, -1.55154482234759, 
1.16716954923568, -0.273645701374081, -0.467845324672254, -1.23825232798621, 
-0.00776203377732663, -0.80028217795166, -0.533492329950436, 
1.28767524558459, -0.175525870242127, -1.07178238415068, 0.163206882467382, 
-0.36273841562795)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))


Here is a way with recordPlot, see also this SO post.
Write the function with an extra argument, file, so that the function only saves to file if needed.
After each plot record the plot and after plotting everything, save the plots in a list to be returned to caller.
F4 <- function(data, file) {
  data <- data[, !colnames(data) %in% "blank"]
  names(data) <- c("district", "confirmed", "deceased", "recovered")
  data[, "active"] <- data$confirmed - data$recovered - data$deceased
  data <- data[, c("district", "active", "confirmed", "recovered", "deceased")]
  data <- data[1:30, ]
  # save default graphics parameters for later
  old_par <- par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  # start 1st plot
  boxplot(data$active, data$confirmed, data$recovered, data$deceased,
          col="skyblue", ylab="No. of Cases", 
          main="Boxplot of COVID-19 status")
  axis(1, at=1, labels="Active")
  axis(1, at=2, labels="Confirmed")
  axis(1, at=3, labels="Recovered")
  axis(1, at=4, labels="Deceased")
  # record 1st plot
  p1 <- recordPlot()
  #
  # start 2nd plot
  barplot(data$confirmed, col="skyblue", ylim=c(0, max(data$confirmed)*1.1), 
          names.arg=1:30, xlab="District", ylab="No. of Cases",
          main="COVID-19 status by region")
  barplot(data$recovered, col="yellowgreen", add=TRUE)
  barplot(data$deceased, col="tomato", add=TRUE)
  legend("topright", legend=c("Confirmed", "Recovered", "Deceased"), 
         fill=c("skyblue", "yellowgreen", "tomato"), horiz=TRUE, cex=0.9)
  # record 2nd plot
  p2 <- recordPlot()
  # put graphics parameters back
  par(old_par)
  # save the plots in a list
  p <- list(p1, p2)
  
  # do we want to save to disk?
  if(!missing(file)) {
    png(file, width = 800, height = 1000)
    lapply(p, replayPlot)
    dev.off()
  }

  # return the plots list to caller
  return(p)
}

# this will plot in RStudio's plots pane
p <- F4(data)

# see if the plots were saved in 'p'
dev.new()
# 'p' is a list, must call replayPlot with lapply
lapply(p, replayPlot)


Created on 2024-06-16 with reprex v2.1.0
The call to dev.new opens a graphics device, a new window. And then the two graphs are plotted. The result is the same as above. Here is a screen capture showing it.

